# How to plot two graphs above?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

How to 
1) have one legent 
2) make the first graph higher 
3) plot secont data in first graph
4) have one x-axes - lower graph 
5) minimalize space between graphs
6) have the same width of graphs

Thank you

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set tmargin 1.8
set bmargin 1.8
set encoding iso_8859_1


unset xlabel
set ylabel "{/:Italic F} [a. u.]" font "Segoe UI,12"
set ytics nomirror font "Segoe UI,12"
set xtics nomirror font "Segoe UI,12"
#set decimalsign ','
set format y "%.2f"
set key at graph 0.78,1 font "Segoe UI,12"
set key out horiz font "Segoe UI,12"
set key tc variable
plot [4272:4500] [0.7:1.02] 'data1.txt' using 1:2 title "F" with lines linecolor rgb "red" lw 1.5, "data2.txt' using 1:3 title "D" with lines linecolor rgb "black" lw 1.5


set xlabel "{/:Italic {/Symbol l}} ({\305})" font "Segoe UI,12"
set ylabel "{/:Italic F} [a. u.]" font "Segoe UI,12"
set ytics nomirror font "Segoe UI,12"
set xtics nomirror font "Segoe UI,12"
#set decimalsign ','
set format y "%.2f"
set key at graph 0.78,1 font "Segoe UI,12"
set key out horiz font "Segoe UI,12"
set key tc variable
plot [4272:4500] 'data1.txt' using 1:4 title "DD - fitted" with lines linecolor rgb "navy" lw 1.5
```

error:

```
plot 'data1.txt' using 1:2 title "Fid" with lines linecolor rgb "red" lw 1.5,"data1.txt' using 1:3 title "Measured" with lines linecolor rgb "bla
ck" lw 1.5"
                                                                                                                        ^
           unexpected or unrecognized token
```

Comment: Use `"data1.txt"` (double-quotes) or `'data1.txt'` (single-quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
reset
set encoding utf8

set tics out nomirror

set style line 1 lc "red"
set style line 2 lc "orange"
set style line 3 lc "blue"

unset xtics
set  ytics
set  ylabel "y-axes"  #tc ls 1

set lmargin screen 0.10
set rmargin screen 0.95


set multiplot layout 2,1

set bmargin screen 0.40
set key Left reverse out horiz

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10] 

plot \
    x w l ls 1 t "x",\
    x + 5 w l ls 2 t "x + 5",\
    1/0 w l ls 3 t "1/0"

set tmargin screen 0.37
set bmargin screen 0.15

#set key left Left reverse
unset key

set tics out nomirror
set  xlabel "x-axes (λαβϵλ = label)"

plot x w l ls 3 t "x"
```

Result
[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you very much and please do you know what is wrong with lines that gives error?

Comment: Is it possible to set different yranges and place y-tics of the second graph on the right side?

Comment: Yes, it is. Use `set yrange` before each `plot` command or `plot [<xmin>:<xmax>][<ymin>:<ymax>]`.

Comment: To tic-marks use `unset ytics`, `set y2tics`, and `set link y2`. If necessary, change `rmargin` and `unset ylabel`.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, don't forget of the mark as answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198752/discussion-between-marcia-cross-and-grsousajr).

Comment: @MarciaCross: Taking this question to chat **does not mean** that you can [post a new question asking for participation in the chat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57734910/62576).